# How to pass props from parent to child component in Vue3JS with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

its my first time in VueJS and we are creating a project in class using typescript.
I need to pass the properties of the tabsData variable from the parent component (the view) to the child (the view component). I pass you the code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
//import { reactive, ref, computed } from "vue";
import ArgumentTabComponent from "./components/ArgumentTabComponent.vue";
import $t from "@/core/utils/i18n/translate";
import Button from "primevue/button";
import type { IntArgumentListData } from "./types/IntArgumentListData";

const tabsData: IntArgumentListData[] = [
  {
    title: "Argumento 1",
    content: "texto1",
  },
  {
    title: "Argumento 2",
    content: "texto2",
  },
  {
    title: "Argumento 3",
    content: "texto3",
  },
  {
    title: "Argumento 4",
    content: "texto4",
  },
  {
    title: "Argumento 5",
    content: "texto5",
  },
];

const handleRedirect = () => {
  alert("Aceptando!");
};
</script>

<template>
  <br />
  <h1>Argumentarios</h1>
  <div class="">
    <ArgumentTabComponent> {{ tabsData }}</ArgumentTabComponent>
    <hr />
    <Button :label="$t('common.accept')" @click="handleRedirect" />
  </div>
</template>
```

I have been searching a lot on the internet and YouTube but everyone uses export default {} but with TypeScript, I can't do it.
What I have tried is to pass the properties as I show you:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import TabView from "primevue/tabview";
import TabPanel from "primevue/tabpanel";

// Lib imports
//import { ref } from "vue";
import type { IntArgumentListData } from "../types/IntArgumentListData";

// Properties
const props = defineProps<{
  title: IntArgumentListData;
  content: IntArgumentListData;
}>();
</script>

<template>
  <br />
  <div class="">
    <TabView>
      <TabPanel v-for="tab in props" :key="tab.title" :header="tab.title">
        <p>{{ tab.content }}</p>
      </TabPanel>
    </TabView>
  </div>
  <br />
</template>
```

But when using this way I am getting a strange error in the parent component:

[error in parent component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYswf.png)

So I'm pretty lost. I've spent many hours trying things and thinking about it but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Thank you all

Message error in English:

The type '{ tabData: IntArgumentListData[]; "tab data": IntArgumentListData[]; }' cannot be assigned to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<{ tabsData: IntArgumentListData[]; }>>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>'.
Property "tabsData" is missing in type "{ tabData: IntArgumentListData[]; "tab-data": IntArgumentListData[]; }", but is required in type "Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<{ tabsData: IntArgumentListData[ ]; }>>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>".ts(2322)

Answer (score 4):

You defined your props as follows:

```
const props = defineProps<{
  title: IntArgumentListData;
  content: IntArgumentListData;
}>();
```

Which means you create two props, one called `title` with a type of `IntArgumentListData` and one called `content` with a type of `IntArgumentListData`.

In your type-definition `IntArgumentListData` you already defined `title` and `content`

So what you want to do is presumably something like this:

```
const props = defineProps<{
  tabsData: IntArgumentListData[];
}>();
```

And in your component you only need to loop over `tabsData`.

***NOTE: When using defineProps the props will be available in the template without using props.tabsData; although in the script setup you need to access it with props.tabsData***

```
 <TabPanel v-for="tab in tabsData" :key="tab.title" :header="tab.title">
```

this prop will then be exposed on the component when used in the parent.
There you will have to bind the data to the prop on component call.

```
 <ArgumentTabComponent :tab-data="tabsData" />
```

**Helpful documentation links:**

- [declaring props in-Depth](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props-declaration)

---

**Can you provide an english translation of the error?**

It should result in something like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
//import { reactive, ref, computed } from "vue";
import ArgumentTabComponent from "./components/ArgumentTabComponent.vue";
import $t from "@/core/utils/i18n/translate";
import Button from "primevue/button";
import type { IntArgumentListData } from "./types/IntArgumentListData";

const tabsData: IntArgumentListData[] = [
  {
    title: "Argumento 1",
    content: "texto1",
  },
  {
    title: "Argumento 2",
    content: "texto2",
  },
  {
    title: "Argumento 3",
    content: "texto3",
  },
  {
    title: "Argumento 4",
    content: "texto4",
  },
  {
    title: "Argumento 5",
    content: "texto5",
  },
];

const handleRedirect = () => {
  alert("Aceptando!");
};
</script>

<template>
  <br />
  <h1>Argumentarios</h1>
  <div class="">
    <ArgumentTabComponent :tabs-data="tabsData" />
    <hr />
    <Button :label="$t('common.accept')" @click="handleRedirect" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Child:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import TabView from "primevue/tabview.vue";
import TabPanel from "primevue/tabpanel.vue";

// Lib imports
//import { ref } from "vue";
import type { IntArgumentListData } from "../types/IntArgumentListData";

// Properties
const props = defineProps<{
  tabsData: IntArgumentListData[];
}>();
</script>

<template>
  <br />
  <div class="">
    <TabView>
      <TabPanel v-for="tab in tabsData" :key="tab.title" :header="tab.title">
        <p>{{ tab.content }}</p>
      </TabPanel>
    </TabView>
  </div>
  <br />
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer. I have added your code:  const props = defineProps<{
  tabsData: IntArgumentListData[];
}>();     but I don't know where put the variable props. And I i still get the same error on <ArgumentTabComponent :tab-data="tabsData" />

Comment: @vlexx I updated the answer to reflect what I mean. the `props` variable will only be necessary if you want to use the props within the `<script>`. The function `defineProps` will expose the props in the `<template>` directly. therefore you can loop over `tab in tabsData` instead of `tab in props.tabsData`

Comment: Thank you very much to waste your time in my problem. I updated the question with the error in English

Comment: wow the error was I put tab-data and it was tabs-data xD Thank you very much, the code works!!